# Delphi - connecting similar procedures

Tags: delphi

I am currently working on one a little bit complex application and I have found one problem. I am going to try to reduce complexity of my application into one simple application, just for example. The point is, that I have 16 regions and there is variables and procedures for each one of them. Each procedure have to be universal for each region. Currently I resolve that by writing one "if" on the beginning of the procedure and them copy that 15 times bellow and changing it little bit, because for each region it makes difference just in a few words. So I have to change that word in each one of them. This makes the code sooo unclear and it is wasting of time. Is there any way, how to write those 16 "ifs" into one? Using something like template or something like that?

Example application:

key code:

```
procedure TForm1.WriteItem;
var item:integer;
begin
  if currentFile='FirstFile' then begin
    Seek(FirstFile,filesize(firstfile)-1);
    read(FirstFile,item);
    inc(item);
    write(FirstFile,item);
  end;

  if currentFile='SecondFile' then begin
    Seek(SecondFile,filesize(SecondFile)-1);
    read(SecondFile,item);
    inc(item);
    write(SecondFile,item);
  end;
end;
```

full version:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzhR4bZa5iBuazJuX0FWQzBXcHM?usp=sharing

Comment: You could turn everything from `seek` to `write` into a procedure that takes your file as one parameter. Reducing the `if`s depends a bit on what exactly `FirstFile` etc. are and how they are connected to `currentFile`

Comment: You should use object oriented programming (OOP) here. For example create a base class, put general code in it, then derive from that class (that could be the region class) to put specific code in it.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that FirstFile, SecondFile and so on are all of type TFile or some descendant of it, so the first change I would make would be to make 'currentFile' of the same type (or ancestor of it). Then, instead of setting your currentFile as a string, you put something like

```
currentFile := FifthFile;
```

for instance.

Then your procedure just becomes

```
procedure TForm1.WriteItem;
var item:integer;
begin
  Seek(CurrentFile,filesize(CurrentFilefile)-1);
  read(CurrentFile,item);
  inc(item);
  write(CurrentFile,item);
end;
```

Better, though, you could pass your file as a parameter, like this

```
procedure TForm1.WriteItem( const CurremtFile : TYourFileType);
var item:integer;
begin
  Seek(CurrentFile,filesize(CurrentFilefile)-1);
  read(CurrentFile,item);
  inc(item);
  write(CurrentFile,item);
end;
```

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments, this procedure does not required any object variables (although your real procedure may). You can make this independent of any object one of two ways: Either move the function out of the object altogether

```
procedure WriteItem( const CurremtFile : TYourFileType);
```

or make it a class procedure

```
class procedure TForm1.WriteItem( const CurremtFile : TYourFileType);
```

As a general principle I prefer the latter method, but I would probably move it to a different class specifically designed to handle this type of functionality (not my form).

Comment: Using state as per the first example is invariably a poor design. Pass a parameter. Furthermore, there's no need for this to be an instance method since it uses no instance variables.

Comment: You are just encouraging poor style, IMHO